# PHP 5.3 mssql support on Linux

Tags: apache-2.2, php, sql-server

I have a RHEL 5 box with `php 5.3` that I am tasked with installing `mssql` support on.  I installed `php53-mssql` and reloaded apache.  It seems that modules were installed to `/usr/lib/php/modules` but my PHP modules are in `/usr/lib64/php/modules` (lib64).  I couldn't just copy those modules into lib64 because they are not the correct ELF CLASS (probably wrong arch).  When trying `mssql_connect()` I get an undefined function error in the Apache error log.  How can I get this to work? php -m shows these DB modules, but no `mssql` ones.

`PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
mysql
mysqli`

Comment: Have you tried just symlinking them? Did you uncomment the module in `php.ini`?

Comment: If they are the wrong type, I doubt symlinking will help, but Ill try.  Yes I uncommented mssql.so in php.ini.

Comment: Exactly where did you get this `php53-mssql`?

Comment: EPEL php53-mssql-5.3.3-1.el5.i386.rpm

Comment: Have you tried downloading the 64bit one?

Comment: Try to install php35-common, you are missing a lot of stuff you really should have. yum install php35-common

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable `mssql` module in `php.ini`. You need to uncomment this line:

```
extension=mssql.so
```

If you can't find it in `php.ini`, then just add it to the end of other `extension` definitions in your `php.ini` file. Restart apache after that.

Comment: I have that line already.